# What is the difference between stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: and stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, url-encoding

What is please the difference between the 2 methods  `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` and `stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` ?

I have read the [NSString Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) several times and still haven't got it.

Also, is there please a way to force those methods to encode "+" signs as well?

In [my iPhone app](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/blob/master/MyGameCenter/MyGameCenter/ViewController.m) I have to urlencode a base64 encoded (i.e. letters, digits, pluses and slashes) avatar and ended up using the `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes` method instead of the above methods...

```
- (NSString*)urlencode:(NSString*)str
{
    return (NSString*)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
        NULL,
        (__bridge CFStringRef) str,
        NULL,
        CFSTR("+/"),
        kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
}
```

Comment: What's the difference between encoding and decoding?

Comment: Ok, I think I get the difference between "encoding" and "decoding". But "Adding" and "Replacing" are less than optimal names for the methods

Comment: It's Apple.  That's how they name things.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` will convert the Unicode* character to the percent escape format.

`stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` will do the opposite, convert the percent escape to the Unicode*.

*Actually not Unicode, but the encoding you choose.

Examples:

```
NSString *rawText = @"One Broadway, Cambridge, MA"; 
NSString *encodedText = [rawText stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Encoded text: %@", encodedText);
NSString *decodedText = [encodedText stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Original text: %@", decodedText);
```

Here’s the output:

```
Encoded text: One%20Broadway,%20Cambridge,%20MA

Original text: One Broadway, Cambridge, MA
```

Disadvantage: `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` doesn’t encode reserved characters like ampersand (&) and slash (/)

Workaround:use Foundation function `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes` instead.

Source: http://cybersam.com/ios-dev/proper-url-percent-encoding-in-ios